# How to change eval ("column") values from code behind

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, eval, datalist

HI , I wan to change the eval("columnName") value from code behind , for instance if price is selected from the drop down list the eval which is in the datalist should changed to eval("price"), if its product then it should change to Eval("product) . Any suggestions or alternatives will be higly appreciated thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<asp:Label ID="someLabel" Text='<%# GetLabelText(Eval("price"), Eval("product")) %>' .. />
```

and

```
public string GetLabelText(Object price, Object product)
{
    if(/* check dropdownlist for price*/)
    {
          return price.ToString();
    }
    /* else */
    return product.ToString(); 


}
```

Comment: can i do for more columns too

Comment: yeah. just pass them to the helper function and add those parameters as object type.